# AMPScript IndexOf Question

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, ampscript

​I'm stumped. I’ve thought long and hard as to how to get “marketable” data from “technical” data and this is what I’ve come up with:

```
%%[
VAR @prod1
IF IndexOf("%%=ContentAreaByName('My Contents\PID')=%%","1") > 0 THEN
    SET @prod1 = 'success'
ELSE
    SET @prod1 = 'fail'
ENDIF
]%%
```

I thought this would work and it does. However, after investigating this, I realized the `IndexOf` function was not referencing the information in the `ContentAreaByName` piece but rather the words `*%%=ContentAreaByName('My Contents\PID')=%%*`

E.g., if you would reference “*PID*” (instead of “*1*”) it would return the VAR success.

Does anyone know how I can get the `IndexOf` function to actually query the `ContentAreaByName` function before producing an output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `%%==%%` syntax is only allowed outside the AMPScript block -- `%%[]%%`.

I'd do it like this:

```
%%[

VAR @prod1, @ca
set @ca = ContentAreaByName('My Contents\PID')

IF IndexOf(@ca,"1") > 0 THEN
  SET @prod1 = 'success'
ELSE
  SET @prod1 = 'fail'
ENDIF

]%% 

<br>prod1: %%=v(@prod1)=%%
```

Comment: Thanks Adam! This worked. Thank you for taking the time to review my question, and reply with an answer that was understandable and correct.